# Can I set the default application sound level in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, usb, audio, volume-mixer

I've got a set of [Logitech S150 USB speakers](http://www.logitech.com/en-gb/product/9448?crid=658) which have a problem with sound levels. Basically there seems to be only two levels (completely silent or ear-splittingly loud) and no middle ground.

Some Google searches later and I've found a [workaround](http://forums.logitech.com/t5/Speakers/S150-USB-speakers-still-too-loud/m-p/448562#M27602) which is to set the master volume to 100% and then all the application volumes to around 10%. This actually seems to work!

The problem is that all new applications start off with a default per-application volume of 100%, which is way too loud.

Is there any way to set the default sound level per application to be only 10% so that all new and existing applications use this level?

Comment: The volume levels are saved [per EXE in the registry](http://superuser.com/questions/384472/how-to-make-windows-7s-volume-mixer-save-individual-volumes-again). AFAIK there's no way to set a limit for as yet unrecognised/un-encountered EXEs.

Comment: I saw that and have managed to find all the keys and even identify which one is used to control the default volume for that app. The problem is that the value is a whole string of hex numbers and there is no obvious way to see how the volume level is encoded in that string. If I could work that out, I could at least write something to run at login that sets (via the registry) the volume level correctly for each app that has been recognised/encountered. It isn't perfect, but might be a start - failing that, I could just buy some decent speakers!

Comment: In case anyone is wondering (three years later), I binned them, bought some speakers with a proper audio jack and vowed never to buy USB speakers again.