# Volume lowers sounds automatically

Tags: windows-7, audio

the volume from my windows 7 computer lowers automatically.

Regarding the several "similar questions" that have been posted to SU.com before, they have never been properly answered.

Questions for reference:

[Windows 7 lowering volume without my consent](https://superuser.com/questions/588259/windows-7-lowering-volume-without-my-consent)

[Windows 7 lowers applications' volume automatically](https://superuser.com/questions/74116/windows-7-lowers-applications-volume-automatically)

My communications button has already been set to "do nothing". Yet a louder sounding program still insists on lowering down other application's volumes.

I fight for the equality of all programs on my PC, help me out please :(

Answer (score 1):

If a louder sound lowers the volume of the rest, your sound is being normalised.

This is usually a driver setting. Creative calls this SVM (Smart Volume Management).

In order to help you better, please provide more details about your soundcard.