# Adobe Flash Player has only half sound

Tags: windows, audio, flash-player

When recently watching a video on youtube, I noticed that the audio seemed quieter than it should be. This is because, for some reason, Windows has limited Flash Player to half of the system volume.

I can set it up again in the Windows audio settings, but as soon as I close all instances of my browser and reopen it again, Flash Player has again only half of its sound.

This issue has occurred on both Windows 7 and Windows 8, using Firefox.

How can I stop Windows from repeatedly reducing Flash Player's volume

Comment: What operating system? What browser? Do you have multiple sound devices? Does sound work properly on other programs or websites?

Comment: You could Try this in win7 http://superuser.com/questions/384472/how-to-make-windows-7s-volume-mixer-save-individual-volumes-again/384492#384492

Comment: @Canadian Luke: OS: Windows 8; Browser: Firefox; Multiple Sound Devices: No; Sound work properly else: Yes. I'll try your solution, Psycogeek.

Comment: Interestingly, I've run into this same issue running Firefox 27.0.1 on Windows 7. Maybe this is an issue related to Firefox. What version of Firefox are you using?