# Volume adjustment logs?

Tags: windows-7, logging, volume-mixer

Are volume adjustments stored anywhere on the computer? For example, if I move the volume slider from 100% to 80%, will this be logged somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

No logged as such (e.g. I wouldn't expect to see an entry in the event log) but certainly retained. I would expect this to be updated in the registry somewhere.

UPDATE: I did a search. The best I found so far is:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\MediaPlayer\Preferences\Volume
```

But that isn't quite what you want as that is the media player playback volume not the system volume.

Also found:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\MPC-HC\MPC-HC\Settings\Volume
```

which is certainly set to the same as my system volume. But didn't change when I changed the master volume.

Note that each app that handles sound seems to retain its own volume setting too.

Comment: Do you know where I should go to get this info? I'm mostly interested in the hour. :D Also, for how long is this info retained?

Comment: @LucreziavanNecker The only info retained is what the current volume levels are, so that they can be reset to that value after a reboot (etc.). There is no in-built log of volume changes (you'd have to setup a solution of some kind to monitor for changes and log them).

Comment: See this other SU question: [Where are the Vista/Win7 Volume Mixer settings stored?](http://superuser.com/questions/284527/where-are-the-vista-win7-volume-mixer-settings-stored)

Comment: @Techie007: no wonder I couldn't spot it, it is far worse than I thought!

Comment: @Techie007: Not sure what "HKEY_CURRENT_USER" means?

Comment: Edit: No need. Did research!

Answer (score 0):

Even if Windows HAD a registry value of the volume, I doubt that it would store previous logs of volume settings. The Window's event viewer doesn't store them either. The only way to achieve this would be via something like making an AUTOHOTKEY script. If this is a relevant solution for you, I'll research the script to build.

Also, if you use a program like [NirSoft](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/sound_volume_view.html), it will save the volume into a file which you can then make a script to extract that data into your own logging file of your choice.

Comment: It appears that volume changes by itself on startup. The slider drops to 80% - 50%. Why does this happen? It hasn't happened before!

Comment: This feature is intended for VOIP communications (but works with other notification sounds, like Windows System noises) to tune out your music if someone calls you or whatever. You can alter or disable it by taking the following steps:

1. winkey -> type "sound options" -> press enter (alternatively, right-click on the default volume icon on your taskbar, select "Sounds")
2. Browse to "Communications" tab
3. Select "Do Nothing"
4. Press ok